# how to transform rows to columns in R

Tags: r, strsplit

I would like to know how to transform rows to columns for the following dataset.

```
School class Avg  Subavg  Sub
ABC     2    25.3  17.2   Geo
ABC     2    25.3  18.2   Mat
ABC     2    25.3  20.2   Fre
ABC     3    21.2  17.2   Geo
ABC     3    21.2  18.2   Mat
ABC     3    21.2  20.2   Ger
ABC     4    16.8  17.2   Ger
ABC     4    16.8  18.2   Mat
ABC     5    20.2  20.2   Fre
```

Expected output would be

```
School Std stdavg  Geo   mat    Ger     Fer
ABC    2    25.3   17.2  18.2   NA      20.2
ABC    3    21.2   17.2  18.2   20.2    NA
ABC    4    25.3   NA    18.2   17.2    NA
ABC    5    25.3   NA    NA     NA      20.2
```

I used split function, But in vain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The 'stdavg' for 4 and 5 in the expected output is not making any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), School+class+Avg~Sub, value.var="Subavg")
#    School class  Avg  Fre  Geo  Ger  Mat
#1:    ABC     2 25.3 20.2 17.2   NA 18.2
#2:    ABC     3 21.2   NA 17.2 20.2 18.2
#3:    ABC     4 24.8   NA   NA 17.2 18.2
#4:    ABC     5 24.8 20.2   NA   NA   NA
```

---

Or use `spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, Sub, Subavg)
```

Comment: Unfortunately (fortunately), this is something we cannot control. And with voting being anonymous (thank god), the chances of teaching a lesson to a random unknown "somebody" is very slim.