# how to convert character values in rows into columns in R

Tags: r, character, row

I want to use a for loop to compute cumulative abnormal returns in R and have the dates in column 1, company names (comn) in 2, and stock prices (prccd) in 3. However, to compute abnormal returns I first need to compute the returns and thus need the company names with subsequent stock prices to be able to do this. Now my df looks like this;

| Date | conm | prccd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-11-02 | X | 1 |
| 2016-11-02 | Y | 2 |
| 2016-11-02 | Z | 3 |

And thus need the data frame to look like:

| Date | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-11-02 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2016-11-03 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2016-11-04 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

Comment: Perhaps you want to reshape your data from long to wide? See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)...including `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to transform your dataframe,`dcast` function in
data.table would help. You can see here ([how to transform rows to columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589719/how-to-transform-rows-to-columns-in-r)) for usage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).